# Rebind jQuery datatable in asp.net gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, datatable

I am using jQuery datatable to bind an asp.net gridview and I have to hide and show some rows.

It is working perfect but when I hide some rows from datatable the datatable paging is not updating so I have to rebind jquery datatable.

When I call the datatable function again it shows this error :-

[image]

I am using this code to show and hide..then rebind datatable

```
$('table.dataTable tbody tr').each(function () {
                var name = $(this).find('.name').html();
                if (name == str) {
                    $(this).show();
                    $('.Flight_class').dataTable({
                        "aaSorting": [[1, "asc"]],
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "bJQueryUI": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        "bLengthChange": false
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is not possible to rebind `datatable`. Unbind it before rebinding:

```
$('.Flight_class').unbind().dataTable({...});
```